# Flutter Web Dynamic Links

Tags: flutter, firebase, web, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to receive the link that directs my Flutter web application using dynamic links, but I'm having trouble accessing dynamic links for web. In my iOS app, dynamic links work when a button is clicked, and they redirect to my domain. How can I achieve this? I want to retrieve the user ID information that comes through the dynamic link. However, dynamic links don't work on the web.

*Not for my own mobile app*

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Dynamic Links is only supported on iOS and Android, not on web. Not only that, but the product is also deprecated and will be sunset in 2025 - so I'd recommend against trying it on your new project.

Instead of trying to use Firebase Dynamic Links, I'd recommend using something like go_router to accomplish the same goal. For more on this, see the Flutter documentation on [UI navigation and routing](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation#:%7E:text=Flutter%20applications%20with%20advanced%20navigation,receives%20a%20new%20deep%20link).

Comment: Thank you. I'm investigating this because it's a requirement of my company. They are implementing referral redirects through the iOS app and I need to get the user ID that comes through the link. I cannot access the user ID sent via Dynamic Links from the Flutter web application I developed. If you have a suggestion, I'd like to investigate.

Comment: That seems a different scope than your original question (iOS vs Web), so I recommend opening a new question for it. I also recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to prevent the new post from being closed for the same reason as this one was closed.

Comment: Okey, thank you again